# How to stop a running python script

Tags: python, pyqt

I created a GUI with PyQt which implements the buttons "Start" and "Stop".
When I click on "Start" a huge python Script is started. The function of "Stop" has to end this python script, but when I start the script it runs and I can't stop it. I even can't activate anything else on the GUI and I get no reaction from it. So i have to wait the long time until the python script ends.
How can I implement the methods so that I can interrupt the script with the "Stop" button even when I want?

Comment: Show us some code. How is the script run? You probably want to make it a thread separate from the interface. GUIs work differently from a simple start-and-stop commandline script, perhaps that's something you still need to get used to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do everything in the QButton.clicked signal, your GUI locks up until you exit that function.

My solution i used in a small project was to seperate it into a GUI and worker process.

Use [multiprocessing.Process](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) to do your processing and have it send the results over a [multiprocessing.Pipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe).
The worker also has a second Pipe to recieve commands (my project just uses one command - exit)

In the GUI, you create 2 Pipes: one for results, one for commands.
Initialize the worker with both pipes and start the process.
The next step would be to have a QTimer poll the pipe for results and display them.

By doing so, your UI stays responsive while the calculations happen in the background.